# Where are magento modules settings stored?

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.6

I'd like to know where are magento modules settings stored?
Are them inside the database?

Because I'm working on a staging server and since we're moving to a new provider then I'd like to dump the db from the production site and take the source code from the staging server.
Would I lose my settings without moving the staging server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default config will be defined and set in

```
/app/code/(local|community)/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/config.xml
```

If there is also a `system.xml` present in the `etc` folder it means there will be some admin config available. These settings will then be saved in the `core_config_data` table in the database.

Comment: Thanks, so I should export core_config_data from the staging server to the production server to avoid resetting all new module configuration?

Comment: No, definitely not. I would install the module on production (just upload it) then go view the settings on staging and copy them to production manually via the admin config pages.

Comment: What if I install them locally (just to keep the code versioned with git while developing on the staging server) and then I upload the code including the modules already installed, and I configure them using the admin interface. is it also a good practice?

Comment: Yes that should be fine, just don't copy the raw database tables over.

Answer (score 1):

Yes Information stored inside core_config_data 
and if you want to uninstall/reinstall the module ( remove the database record in core_resource  that has the module name ) then when you open the browser next time it will re-install the module etc..